# Bootstrap nav bar and font awesome issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I want to add font awesome in nav-bar bootstrap but it showing this kind of problem

[image]

My problem is i want to user bigger icon size but it is not center aligning

I can solve it by giving absolute position to icon and extra left margin to text.
But is there any proper solution for this

[Demo: http://www.bootply.com/MgKvoq91WI](http://www.bootply.com/MgKvoq91WI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to icon class:

```
.fa-2x{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See updated [**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/4TplcPI4KD)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace below line in your html

```
<li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <b>Create New</b></a></li>
```

`fa fa-plus fa-*` change in icon size, but in your case no need to use.

Comment: my problem is i want to user bigger icon size but it is not center aligning

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <b>Create New</b></a></li>
```

You use `class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"` class that why this show bigger.